# How to terminate a python process similar to ctrl-c?

Tags: bash, terminal, python

If I have several Terminal windows open, each running a python script, is there a way to terminate one by PID as if I pressed ctrl-c?

With ctrl-c the script exits gracefully, but I tried various `kill -s` commands and they all caused it to terminate without catching the script's main (infinite) `while` loop.

There are some 'cleanup' actions that get performed after `ctrl-c`.

Comment: `kill -2 PID` is equivalent to `Ctrl-C`, but I don't know if they will break into a CPU loop.

Comment: @AFH Yes, that did it! Accepted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> generates signal number 2 (`SIGINT`). The same signal is generated by:

```
kill -2 PID
```

or:

```
kill -SIGINT PID
```

You can list all the signal numbers and names with:

```
kill -l
```

Comment: Or just `kill -INT PID` for short!

Comment: @ShouYa - Thanks, I'd forgotten that the `SIG` prefix is optional.